# Forwarding Outlook emails based on specific content in attachments

Tags: regex, vba, email, outlook, forwarding

Creating a custom rule for forwarding emails based on the content of the attachments. I don't know how to use regex on the content of the attachments.

See code - I think I only do the Regex for the content of the email not for the content of the attachments.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Forward(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match
    Dim Reg1 As Object
    Dim myForward As Object

    Set Reg1 = New RegExp

    With Reg1
        .Pattern = "(Next year\s*(\w*)\s*)"
        .Global = True
    End With

    If Reg1.Test(Item.Body) Then
        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(Item.Body)
        For Each M In M1
            Debug.Print M.SubMatches(0) ' Immediate Window

            Item.Subject = Item.Subject & " - Next year"
            Item.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Assignments for next year. </BODY></HTML>" & objForward.HTMLBody

        Next
    End If

    Item.Save

    Set myForward = Item.Forward
    myForward.Recipients.Add "a@aaa.aa"
    myForward.Display
End Sub
```

I want the output to be:
- Forward email
   - New Subject: [Item.Subject] & " - Next year"

The emails to be forwarded:
- Emails containing attachments which contains the text: "Next year"

Comment: what is the format of attachment .txt or pdf or something else

Comment: The format of the attachment is .pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the Outlook Object Model specifically that will provide access to a file attachment's contents, aside from facilitating saving the attachment to disk. You will need to use additional APIs for each proprietary file content type that you want to parse. VBA does have the Open command that will let you read text files.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. 

Just to make sure - the short answer to my question is No then, right?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you are definitely limited using VBA. A .NET COM add-in would give you more choices for using additional APIs to read various file contents. Although since Word can open .pdfs, you could use the Word Object Model to parse it.

Comment: In short, I am very new to VBA so forgive me if my questions are poor.

If the Word Object Model can open .pdfs and parse it ->
Do I need to download each .pdf-attachment (one mail at a time) to use the Word Object Model to parse the text?

Or is there a better way?

And can you by any chance help me with some code / pseudo-code?

Thank you for your great answers so far!

Comment: Yes you need to save the attachments to disk so you can open them with Word. If you have a specific question about using Word then please post a separate question if you cannot find the answer from your own research. There is plenty of documentation on how to use the Word Object Model, like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/vba/api/overview/word. Otherwise, StackOverflow is not a code writing service

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your help.
I'll have a closer look at the Word Object Model.